Microsoft ML: The prediction code always predicts 0 but when tried in the Evaluate tab it always works (a value other than 0)
System Information:

Model Builder Version17.15.0.2337001
Visual Studio Version 2022

I created a machine learning model (Value Prediction), everything's fine

By this image, you see that model working normal
But when I use the code by the model builder:
using ConsoleApp2;

//Load sample data
var sampleData = new MLModel1.ModelInput()
{
    Device = 1F,
    Temperature = 20F,
    Weather = 1F,
    Time = 2F,
};

//Load model and predict output
var result = MLModel1.Predict(sampleData);
Console.WriteLine(result.Predict);

The output alway is 0 or the predict alway is 0:


As the working sample data, it doesn't contain the unit:
var sampleData = new MLModel1.ModelInput()
{
    Device = 1,
    Temperature = 20,
    Weather = 1,
    Time = 2,
};
```

